# Numbering equation using eqnarray*

Tags: math-mode

I am using eqnarray to write long equations. However when I use it instead of equation environment the equations are not numbered. Can anyone help me to solve this.

This is the syntax that I am using.

```
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f_{lin}(z) & = &  f(z_{0}) + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\theta}}\bigg|_{z = z_{0}}\ddot{\theta} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\alpha}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\ddot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\dot{\theta} \\
& &  + \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\alpha}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\dot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \theta}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\theta + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \alpha}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\alpha
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: [Don't use eqnarray](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/575)

Comment: The `*` form means don't number use `eqnarray` to get a number (but better to use `align`)

Answer (score 11):

In addition to recommending that you use the `align` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) instead of the `eqnarray*` environment, I would also suggest you make each line's first `+` symbol the alignment point, rather than the `=` symbol; that way, the structure of the equation should become very readily apparent. And, since the string `\bigg|_{z = z_{0}}` occurs no fewer than six times, it's handy to create a shortcut macro for it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides the "align" environment
\newcommand\atz{\bigg\vert_{z=z_0}\!} % a shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
f_{\textit{lin}}(z) =  f(z_{0}) 
&+ 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\theta}}\atz \ddot{\theta} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\alpha}}\atz \ddot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\atz \dot{\theta} \notag \\ 
&+ \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\alpha}}\atz \dot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \theta}\atz \theta + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \alpha}\atz \alpha
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the `align` environment, you could use a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment; the main difference is that there's a single equation number that's centered vertically across the rows of the `equation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\atz{\bigg\vert_{z=z_0}\!} % a shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
f_{\textit{lin}}(z) =  f(z_{0}) 
&+ 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\theta}}\atz \ddot{\theta} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\alpha}}\atz \ddot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\atz \dot{\theta} \\[1ex] % some additional vertical separation
&+ \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\alpha}}\atz \dot{\alpha} + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \theta}\atz \theta + 
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \alpha}\atz \alpha
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in this case, `aligned` would work the same as split within a single `equation`.

Comment: +1 `split` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Load ackage `amsmath` and then use:

```
\begin{align} 
f_{lin}(z) & =  f(z_{0}) + 
  \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\theta}}\bigg|_{z = z_{0}}\ddot{\theta} + 
  \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \ddot{\alpha}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\ddot{\alpha} + 
  \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\dot{\theta} \\\nonumber
& \quad  + \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \dot{\alpha}}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\dot{\alpha} + 
  \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \theta}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\theta + 
  \frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \alpha}\bigg |_{z = z_{0}}\alpha
\end{align}
```

Comment: Solves my problem